# is the word 'mean' an uncountable noun

Tags: means

In math, is the word "mean" used only in singular form? Can it be used in plural form, like this:

The means of DSW and SDA were 5.89±1.8 mm, and 12.37±4.09° respectively.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use “means” just like you did. It’s not an uncountable noun.